# How does this css compatible with Google Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

That css is compatible with Firefox, but it isnt with google chrome. In Chrome is transparent!

```
.hubsimular{ 
    background: url("../img/hub/controls.png") no-repeat top right, -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(208, 208, 208, 1.0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 50%, rgba(208, 208, 208, 1.0));
}
```

The background image is semitransparent, and the color degraded is underneath of the background image.

In this image can see the problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPyCi.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
hubsimular{ 
background: url("../img/hub/controls.png") no-repeat top right, -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(208, 208, 208, 1.0),-webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(208, 208, 208, 1.0),linear-gradient(rgba(208, 208, 208, 1.0),rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 50%, rgba(208, 208, 208, 1.0)); }
```

You should have a fall back option and `webkit` option in addition to `moz`

Comment: This rule will just get discarded in every browser, no?

Comment: ie9 and below will not support gradients.

Comment: My point is that the rule uses both `-moz-linear-gradient` and `-webkit-linear-gradient` in the `background` value, so it will be discarded as an invalid value by all non-Mozilla browsers because of the former and by Mozilla browsers because of the latter.  You want multiple `background` declarations with the various prefixed values, not one with all the values in it.

Answer (score 4):

It's because you're using only `-moz-linear-gradient`. You need to use `-webkit-linear-gradient` as well

Answer (score 0):

Add

`-webkit-linear-gradient(left, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%);`